# php file_get_contents() get data

Tags: php, url, echo, file-get-contents

I have got this code:

```
$url = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=".$name;
$url = file_get_contents($url);
echo $url;
```

The output of this is

```
{
    "success":true,
    "lowest_price":"4,20\u20ac",
    "volume":"4,855",
    "median_price":"4,16\u20ac"
}
```

and I want just the `lowest_price`. How can i select it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

The output you're getting is called **JSON String**. You can parse this into array using [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

```
<?php
     $JSON_STRING="{"success":true,"lowest_price":"4,20\u20ac","volume":"4,855","median_price":"4,16\u20ac"}";
     $array=json_decode($JSON_STRING,true);
```

Above code converts the Json String into array and you can access `lowest_price` like this (just like you access any value in array),

```
<?php
    echo $array["lowest_price"];
```

Second parameter in **json_decode()** denotes to convert the JSON String to Array, by default it returns **PHP Object.**

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    $url = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=".$name;
    $url = file_get_contents($url);
    echo $url;
    $data = json_decode($url, true);
    $lowest_price = $data['lowest_price'];
    echo $lowest_price;
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, on line 5 you'll need to do $lowest_price->{'lowest_price'} because json_decode by default returns an object array and not an assoc array. And why are you using the same variable name and implicitly overwriting $lowest_price, just looks confusing to me.

Comment: oh, i forgot : json_decode($url, true); true means make an array :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```
$url = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=".$name;
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($data);
$lowest_price = $json->{'lowest_price'};
echo $lowest_price;
```